# Union Select not displaying Union Results

Tags: mysql, join, union

Hey guys so my query isn't returning my union results when I specify my main selects column names, aka

```
SELECT inspection_number, region, report_date, 
inspection_type AS type, customer, customer_number, shipper, po
FROM reports
JOIN (
    (

        SELECT `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`
        FROM `berries`
    )
    UNION (

        SELECT `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`
        FROM `melons`
    )
    UNION (

        SELECT `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`
        FROM `citrus`
    )
    UNION (

        SELECT `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`
        FROM `table_grapes`
    )
    UNION (

        SELECT `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`
        FROM `tree_fruit`
    )
    UNION (

        SELECT `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`
        FROM `lot`
    )
) fruits ON inspection_number = fruits.report_key
WHERE fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1'
ORDER BY report_date DESC
```

Does not return `key`, `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, or `status`

Strangely running

```
SELECT *
inspection_type AS type, customer, customer_number, shipper, po
FROM reports
JOIN ( -- etc.....
```

Will? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **fruits** derived table does have the columns mentioned but in your main select you don't mention any of them; you only mention the columns inspection_number, region, report_date, inspection_type from reports - therefore it only shows them.

If you want to include the fruits columns, you need to specify them in your main select statement

i.e. something like:

```
SELECT inspection_number, region, report_date, 
inspection_type, key, report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, status AS type, customer, customer_number, shipper, po, key, report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, status
FROM reports
JOIN (
```